Package installation issue in conda: PackagesNotFoundError
I'm new to working with conda environments. I'm trying to install this package from github using conda but it is throwing a PackagesNotFoundError error.
git clone https://github.com/mmiladi/MutaRNA.git
cd MutaRNA
conda env create -f conda-env-MutaRNA.yml -n MutaRNA

and then I get this error:
 Channels:
 
 - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
  - r
  - conda 

Platform: linux-64 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done solving environment: failed
 
 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
 current channels:
 
   - gcc_impl_linux-64==7.3.0=habb00fd_2
   - gdk-pixbuf==2.36.12=haf2c3b9_1004
   - gxx_impl_linux-64==7.3.0=hdf63c60_2
 
 Current channels:
 
   - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
   - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
   - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/linux-64
   - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda/linux-64
 
 To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
 you're looking for, navigate to
 
     https://anaconda.org
 
 and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I tried installing gcc_impl_linux-64==7.3.0=habb00fd_2 directly from the URL but it still doesn't solve the issue.
conda install https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gcc_impl_linux-64/7.3.0/download/linux-64/gcc_impl_linux-64-7.3.0-habb00fd_2.tar.bz2

Although the missing packages come under the conda-forge channel it is somehow not able to detect.

You can use "conda search" and see what packages are available. For me, the build is wrong it is either "habb00fd_0" or "habb00fd_1" I don't necessarily have all of the same channels as you though.

It's the same for me as well. Can't find "habb00fd_2" on the list

The packages are still there, but have been moved to a different label ("broken") so they do not appear in the "main" returns from the conda-forge channel.  If you look for the packages on https://anaconda.org, you can still find them.
I.e. here you can see gcc_impl_linux-64==7.3.0=habb00fd_2 but it has been moved to the label broken.  The same is true for gdk-pixbuf==2.36.12=haf2c3b9_1004 and gxx_impl_linux-64==7.3.0=hdf63c60_2.
To install these, you would need to add that label's subchannel to the install command:
conda env create -f conda-env-MutaRNA.yml -n MutaRNA -c conda-forge/label/broken

This will install them, but the broken label should give you pause as to how well this will work.

Did you mean "-C" because "-c" is an invalid argument? I'm still getting this error: SpecNotFound: conda-forge/label/broken was not found on anaconda.org.
You may need to be logged in. Try running: anaconda login
